# Performance Help on 144 million row table query SQL - Very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, large-data

I need help with my query. This table has 144 million rows and this is a stage table ( where we insert data from another table). I didn't have indexes before and the job had been running for more than 9 hours. I added the non clustered index to this table with multiple columns ( AdvertiserName,MediaPlanName,MediaPlanNumber, CreativeDescription) because this combination makes it unique. But even now execution plan shows Table Scan and not non-clustered index scan and no improvement with performance.

This is the query below, and it is taking very long time to summarize data into csv file using SSIS. How can I improve performance on this query? Please help!!
It is taking very long time to run. :(

```
SELECT
    AdvertiserName,
    AdvertiserID,
    MediaPlanNumber,
    MediaPlanName,
    PublishingSiteName,
    SiteName,
    Week_Begin_Monday,
    CreativeDescription,
    SUM(CAST(ViewCount AS BIGINT)) ViewCount,
    SUM(CAST(ClickCount AS BIGINT)) ClickCount,
    Media,
    Segment_Name,
    Segment_CD,
    Group_Name,
    Group_CD,
    Channel,
    LOB,
    Creative_Message,
    Creative_Category,
    Creative_Type,
    SUM(GRP) GRP,
    Intended_Delivery_Screen

FROM Stage_MM240(NOLOCK)
GROUP BY    AdvertiserName,
            AdvertiserID,
            MediaPlanNumber,
            MediaPlanName,
            PublishingSiteName,
            SiteName,
            Week_Begin_Monday,
            CreativeDescription,
            Media,
            Segment_Name,
            Segment_CD,
            Group_Name,
            Group_CD,
            Channel,
            LOB,
            Creative_Message,
            Creative_Category,
            Creative_Type,
            Intended_Delivery_Screen
```

Comment: if `( AdvertiserName,MediaPlanName,MediaPlanNumber, CreativeDescription)` makes a row unique and you're including those columns in your group by, then wouldn't each group contain only 1 row?

Comment: Hi FuzzyTree, Thanks for responding to my question. Yes it is  not unique anymore with all of the other columns. So should I create a index on all of the columns? I am lost, not sure what to do?

Comment: are you looking for a specific range of rows? or data from those rows? can you possibly minimize how much data the query is selecting and reading with some WHERE or LIMIT in there?

Comment: it seems you have a lot of information (besides number of rows) in your table. maybe you should consider [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 2):

With no WHERE clause, the fastest execution will always be via a Table Scan. If it used any index except a unique clustered index (basically a PK) it would double the disk accesses.

I would suggest you try to limit the data you're making it read. If you can't, you're just going to have to wait...

Comment: Or buy faster hardware, especially disks.

Answer (score 0):

Normal indexes wont help in this case, since there is no where condition to limit the rows,
You should probably try to explore one of the following:
1. Usage of [MAXDOP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2013/09/27/how-it-works-maximizing-max-degree-of-parallelism-maxdop.aspx) parameter to make use of parallelism
2. If you are using SSIS, try the possibility of replacing these statements with [BULK INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) command
3. Try looking at [columnstore indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088.aspx) which is specially suited for bulk reads and large data since it makes use of compression
4. Try using INCLUDE clause in your non clustered indexes. Covering INDEXES can be used to physically maintain the data in the same order as is required by the queries’ result sets reducing the need for SORT operations later (I would not go for this option)